# Why "is" not "are"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

The original sentence:

> **The bulk and weight of coal** required in the majority of manufacturing industries **is** large in comparison with the bulk and weight of other raw materials.

Answer (score 1):

The singular "is" is used because the author intended to use "the bulk and the weight" as a single item, not as two.

Comment: thanks. Is this style typical when writing about "The A and B of an uncountable noun"?

Comment: I am not sure. It depends on the sentence, and on the intentions of the author. It is not bad, but it can create some confusion to some listeners.

Comment: @Charlie Note that *are* would also have been fine—because the author would have then considered *bulk* and *weight* as separate items. (We assume that the author is using the syntax that conforms to their intention.)